# cardinality of the set of all partitions of $\mathbb N$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Calculate $|A|$ with $A=\{ F \subset \mathcal P(\mathbb N): F \text{ is a partition of } \mathbb N\}$. A partition of $\mathbb N$ is a family of subsets $F=\{P_i\}_{i \in I} \subset \mathcal P(\mathbb N)$, non-empty such that $\bigcup_{i \in I} P_i= \mathbb N$ and $P_i \cap P_j= \emptyset$

My attempt at a solution:

I think that $|A|=c$

I could prove that $c\leq |A|$

I've defined a surjective function $f$, with $f:A \to\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$ as follows:

$f(F)=\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ such that $a_n=1$ if $\{n\} \in F$ or $a_n=0$ if $\{n\} \not \in F$.

Lets check for surjectivity:

If $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N} \in  \{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$, choose $F \in A$ as $F=(\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N : a_n=1} \{\{n\}\}) \cup (\{\mathbb N \setminus \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N : a_n=1} \{n\}\})$, then, clearly $f(F)=\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ by how I've constructed the partition $F$.

This proves $c=|\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}|\leq |A|$

I need help to show the other inequality, and also, I would like to know if this part of the proof is ok. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, what you’ve done works fine. Another approach that is perhaps just a little simpler is to let $E=\{2n:n\in\Bbb N\}$, and for each $A\subseteq E$ let $\mathscr{P}(A)=\{A\cup\{1\},\Bbb N\setminus(A\cup\{1\})\}$; then $\mathscr{P}$ is an injection from $\wp(E)$ to the family of partitions of $\Bbb N$.

To get the other inequality, notice that every partition of $\Bbb N$ is a countable subset of $\wp(\Bbb N)$. If $\mathscr{P}$ is a partition of $\Bbb N$, we can list the members of $\mathscr{P}$ in increasing order of their smallest elements; this uniquely associates to $\mathscr{P}$ a specific sequence, possibly finite, of subsets of $\Bbb N$. If the sequence is finite, we can extend it to an infinite sequence by repeating the last term of the finite sequence.

Thus, it suffices to show that there are at most $\mathfrak{c}$ infinite sequences of subsets of $\Bbb N$. This is equivalent to showing that there are at most $\mathfrak{c}$ infinite sequences of functions from $\Bbb N$ to $\{0,1\}$. If ${}^XY$ denotes the set of functions from $X$ to $Y$, find a bijection between ${}^{\Bbb N\times\Bbb N}\{0,1\}$ and ${}^{\Bbb N}\{0,1\}$ to complete the proof.

Comment: I like your alternative solution. I have a few questions: this may be a stupid remark, but I suppose I have to discard the sets $A=\emptyset$ and $A=E$ from the domain of $\mathcal P$ since $\mathcal P(A)$ has to be a partition of $\mathbb N$. Another doubt that I have is: you've said "notice that every partition of $\mathbb N$ is a countable subset of $\wp(\Bbb N)$. Wouldn't a partition be a countable subset of $\wp(\wp(\Bbb N))$ For example $F=\{\{1\},\{\mathbb N \setminus \{1\}\}$ is a partition of $\mathbb N$ and it is not in $\wp(\Bbb N)$. Thanks very much for the answer.

Comment: @user100106: You have to discard $\varnothing$, but not $E$: $\{E,\Bbb N\setminus E\}$ is just the partition of $\Bbb N$ into evens and odds. We can avoid that by letting $\mathscr{P}(A)=\{A\cup\{1\},\Bbb N\setminus(A\cup\{1\})\}$, and I’ve now made that small technical change. A partition is a family of subsets of $\Bbb N$, so it’s a subset of $\wp(\Bbb N)$ and an **element** of $\wp(\wp(\Bbb N))$.

Comment: Oh, I forgot what $E$ was (I was thinking $E$ as if it was $\mathbb N$, god knows why). And thanks for clearing up the other thing.

Comment: @user100106: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 4):

You've done the hard part.

$A$ has as elements countable sequences from $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$, i.e. it's a subset of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})^{\mathbb{N}}$, so all you need to do is exhibit bijections
$$\left(\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}\right)^{\mathbb{N}} \cong \{ 0, 1 \}^{\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}} \cong \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$$
to get that
$$|A| \le |\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})^{\mathbb{N}}| = \mathfrak{c}$$

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct.

For the second part: one way to do it is the following.  First show that for such a partition $F = \{P_i\}_{i\in I}$, $I$ is at most countable.  Then, identify each such family $F = \{P_i\}_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$  (or $F = \{P_i\}_{0\leq i \leq m}$) with the function $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ given by $f(n) = i$ if $n \in P_i$.  This gives an injection from $A$ to $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$. Now you just need to prove (or recall, if you already know it) that the cardinality of the set of functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ is $\mathfrak{c}$.